# Facebook Live simulcasting policy

Tags: facebook, youtube, twitch.tv

Facebook has the [tad annoying policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#liveAPI) where it doesn't allow users to stream to them and third party websites at the same time (e.g., Twitch, Youtube). For users with a small to near no fan base, this makes gaining maximum traction on a stream more difficult than it needs to be.

Are there alternative methods to allow multiple platforms such as delays on the stream on other platforms, different overlays, etc.?

Comment: I don't think their enforcement of the rules is really something an end-user could answer with any reliability.  I think with that portion omitted, this could be answerable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the technical bit: You need streaming computers (aka servers, physical or virtual doesn't matter) which get fed by your main computer with a clean feed (no overlays) and feed the streaming platforms you want to stream to with the individual delay settings and overlays you want to.

> For users with a small to near no fan base, this makes gaining maximum traction on a stream more difficult than it needs to be.

While an exclusivity clause is annoying, it's not unique to facebook: Twitch has the very same policy for their partners, YouTube does not.

If you interact with your chat at all, you generally want to avoid to stream on multiple platforms at once, and you especially don't want to stream on multiple platforms with different delay settings.

Unlike other forms of content, the strength of  live content with viewer interaction is the building of communities: You may just have 5 viewers regularly appearing in chat, but you can count on them appearing and chatting with each other and you each time you stream. If you have the same 5 viewers split over 3 platforms for the sake of discoverability, you won't get any chatting between them, and it's way more likely that random people stopping by will just leave again because just-you isn't interesting enough for them whereas you+chat might be. Different delays make it even more confusing to what people in chat are referring to than it already is. 
If you don't interact with chat at all, you need to carry the show on your own, which is *a lot* harder – effectively, you're doing a VOD but without the option to cut out the boring bits. I don't recommend going this way.

So, to grow your fanbase, you don't really need (or rather: you really don't need) to stream on every platform at once, but instead focus on building a community in which as many people as possible feel welcome.

Alas, we've moved well beyond the scope of this forum here, so I'm going to just drop some links for further reading and discussion

- [is there a stackexchange for video production and live streaming?]
- The [YouTube creator academy](https://creatoracademy.youtube.com/) has courses regarding live content and general tips on audience growth, regardless of platform
- [YouTube's official creator community](https://www.youtube-creatorcommunity.com)